# Changing kendo-dateinput placeholder for Kendo Angular2

Tags: placeholder, kendo-ui-angular2

Is there a way to change or simply remove the placeholder of the Kendo UI - Angular 2 dateinput control?
Right now, when empty, it reads "day/month/year" and I need to, at least, remove the localized literals.

Thank you very much,
Dimitris

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** With the latest changes in the DateInput (as of v1.4.0) two additional properties were added:

- placeholder - display text hint (related Github issue)
- formatPlaceholder - control description of the format sections (Github issue)

With those available, we can easily hide or modify the displayed format description:

```
<kendo-datepicker [placeholder]="Enter date..." [formatPlaceholder]="short" />
```

Here is a plunker demo that demonstrates those new properties:

http://plnkr.co/edit/XYmwDjkpp7Mb4txlmc2L?p=preview

---

Indeed, the DateInput component displays the localized format value once empty. That being said, its value is controlled by the component date format. Its behavior is similar to the Chrome's `<input type="date" />`.

I'm afraid that the placeholder cannot be set to a custom text.

I think that it will be best to share your request in the Kendo UserVoice portal:

http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback